# Sorting DOB with and without using java inbuild methods

Tags: java

After taking the input from user, e.g., student like Name, phone no, DOB, how to sort the students by their DOB with and without using java inbuild methods?

Comment: For loops and comparisons. Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 4):

```
Use Comparator to sort by date 
Following code may help you

class Comp implements Comparator< Date >
{
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        return -( o1.compareTo( o2 ) ); //implement here order you want
    }


}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dates[] = { "05-11-2014" , "23-08-2014" , "05-02-2013" };
    List< Date > list = new ArrayList< Date >();
    for ( String string : dates ) {
        try {
            Date localdate = sdf.parse(string);
            list.add( localdate );
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Collections.sort( list );

    System.out.println( list );

    Collections.sort( list, new Comp() );

    System.out.println( list );
}
```